# realex payment I get a response but how to display it in a formatted way

Tags: realex-payments-api

i have 2 controllers in my web api one that  generate the request and the second that grabs the response back. in my html page i have the following code taken from releax payment.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="rxp-hpp.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $.getJSON("URL for my request controller", function(jsonFromRequestEndpoint) {
        RealexHpp.setHppUrl("https://pay.sandbox.realexpayments.com/pay");
        // When using full page redirect your Response URL must be an absolute link
        RealexHpp.redirect.init("payButtonId", "URL for my second controller", jsonFromRequestEndpoint);
      });
    });
</script>
```

i get no errors the payment is successful but the data is displayed as a json when ever the payment is successful, the page it is displayed in seemed to be dynamic and i have no controller over it, hence cant format it.  what i want to achieve is when the  payment is successful, i want to display certain data from the large json response in a formatted way.... any help would be appreciated

Comment: if you have more questions, please ask them in the other question your created: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53668668/realex-payment-response-cant-be-handled-net/53750095#53750095

Comment: Possibly related [to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53668668/realex-payment-response-cant-be-handled-net).